# How to reopen Jupyter notebook if I closed the tab?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, julia

This is an extremely basic question. At some point I accidentally closed the window containing my Jupyter notebook tabs. It's gone from my 'recently closed tabs' in Chrome. Is there some way that I can reopen the notebooks corresponding to the currently active kernels?

In case it makes a difference, they are julia kernels, and I started the notebook server by typing `notebook()` in a julia REPL session.

Comment: go to your notebook home, `Running` tabs?

Comment: @QuangHoang how does one go to one's notebook home? All my tabs are closed, including that one.

Comment: You can also bring back any closed tab by searching for it  from the browser history (CTRL+H) or open the last closed tab (can be used repeatedly) with the CTRL+SHIFT+T keyboard shortcut, which most browsers support.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your server is still running, you can still see all previously opened notebooks:

1. Access your [dashboard](https://jupyter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/running.html#starting-the-notebook-server) via the browser (usually `http://localhost:8888` by default).
2. Select the Running Tab (as mentioned by @Quang Hoang).

**Example**

[image]

Comment: How do I access my dashboard? That tab is not open either.

Comment: Thanks. That seems a bit of a fail in terms of discoverability (how on Earth is the user supposed to know that?) but I have my tabs back now.

Comment: I can't speak to the design.   The dashboard should pop up automatically when you start jupyter.  Personally I bookmark this page.  Also, when you see an answer you like, please mark it as complete (green arrow) to make finding answers easier on SO.

Comment: To those curious about the advanced feature I mentioned in comments, here is a post on the [accepted filter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199305/filter-using-accepted-answers).  Here is also the [code of conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct).

Answer (score 1):

As the same happened to me and the first google result was this entry, here is some additional information:

When following the url posted above (`http://localhost:8888`), you may be asked for a password or token, the latter of which you will find either in the Jupyter terminal window (also providing you with the direct notebook url):

[Jupyter terminal screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AhYbu.png)

, or, if using Anaconda, by opening the "Anaconda Prompt" and entering `jupyter notebook list`.